# How proxy all request that comes to some path like "/app*" to an EC2 instance using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Right now I have a site hosted in S3 and delivery through Cloudfront and I have an application running on an EC2 instance. the problem is I need to serve the application using a folder in the domain associated with the CloudFront distribution, eg. example.com/app/

I know I can create a rule in the CloudFront distribution and process the request with a lambda function but seems like is not a good way to do it because I'll need to create a reliable proxy function and handle probably a lot of things

How proxy all request that comes to some path like "/app*" to an EC2 instance using Cloudfront?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so it says what you're trying to do, ideally with examples or a diagram, rather than just asking how to implement the solution you have in mind. I'm pretty sure CloudFront can send some paths to S3 and some to EC2 / ELB easily, without the use of lambda.

Comment: I have changed the question to be more explicit @Tim thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one origin with CloudFront, one of them will be S3 and the other the domain for your EC2 instance.

Then use `CacheBehavior: PathPattern` to proxy `/app` requests to your EC2 origin and DefaultCacheBehavior to proxy all the rest to S3 origin.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-pathpattern

Comment: *proxy `/app` requests* should probably be either (simple) `/app*` or (more precise) both `/app` and `/app/*`.